# Tableau: Aggregate and Non-aggregate comparsion with date

Tags: tableau-api

Getting aggregate and Non-aggregate error with Date calculations when trying to this

IF [date_time]=(max([date_time])) then [Milestone 143 Actual Date Last] END

Please help me to resolve the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Last()` function to get the max date and filter it to `0`
and drag the  `[Milestone 143 Actual Date Last]` to the view.

or try using this :

```
IF attr([date_time])=(max([date_time])) then [Milestone 143 Actual Date Last] END
```

Comment: you could post some sample data? or give the `twbx` ?

Comment: Hi, what I am trying to do here is there are 5-6 date columns are there along with Site_Carrier column in that one of date column name is date_time. Sometime what happens that enginner enters different dates for the same Site_carrier 2-3 times. Now the logic that I deriving that is take out the max(date_time) then take all other dates based upon that max(date_time). Hope this help in understanding the logic.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of problem is one of the reasons Tableau introduced level of detail (LOD) calculations. You are trying to compare values based on different levels of granularity -- e.g. The max value for a set of data rows versus the value for a single row.

Read about LOD calcs.

The solution will involve wrapping your call to max in an LOD calc 
like

```
{ exclude : max([date_time]) }
```

Change the phrase before the colon as needed for your situation